# Array object assigning issue

Tags: typescript

I'm developing a small typescript app and stuck in value assigning.

Here are interfaces.

```
export interface SearchTexts {
    SearchText: SearchText[];
}

export interface SearchText {
    Value: string;
    BusinessID: string;
}
```

Assign values like this.

```
let serchTextArr: SearchText[] = [];
const invoiceNos: string[] = ["INV4587965", "INV4589654"];

for (var idx in invoiceNos) {
  let searchText: SearchText = {
    Value: invoiceNos[idx],
    BusinessID: "BSD458"
  };    
  serchTextArr.push(searchText);
}

let searchTexts: SearchTexts;
searchTexts.SearchText = serchTextArr; //Getting error when assigning
```

Below is the error

```
(node:17661) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot set property 'SearchText' of undefined
```

I used console.log for displaying whether the serchTextArr doesn't have values or not. But it has values and still cant figure out the issue. Can anyone tell me where the issue is?

Comment: let searchTexts: SearchTexts = {SearchText: []};

Comment: Thanks very much @ttquang1063750... you saved my time.... thanks again....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, you've tried to access an object called `searchTexts` which you haven't defined (or shown that you have). Which would explain the error message:

> cannot read SearchText of **undefined**

The simple solution to this to declare the variable like how @ttquang1063750 says to do it:

```
const searchTexts: SearchTexts = {SearchText: []};
```

Just outside your `for` loop.

Comment: No prob! glad to help out